# Does monocolored hybrid mana count within that color's identity?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is [Beseech the Queen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeseech%20the%20Queen%5d) in my commander colors identity? My commander is [Drana, Kalastria Bloodchief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrana%2c%20Kalastria%20Bloodchief%5d).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you think it wouldn't be included in Drana's color identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its color identity is black so you can play it in any deck that includes black in its commander's color identity (like Drana).

A hybrid mana symbol grants the color of both sides of the symbol to the color identity of the card. However Beseech the Queen uses {2/B} hybrid symbols which are colorless and black. Since colorless is not a color black is the only color added to the cards color identity.

> **107.4e** Hybrid mana symbols are also colored mana symbols. Each one represents a cost that can be paid in one of two ways, as represented by the two halves of the symbol. A hybrid symbol such as {W/U} can be paid with either white or blue mana, and a monocolored hybrid symbol such as {2/B} can be paid with either one black mana or two mana of any type. **A hybrid mana symbol is all of its component colors.**
>
> **903.4.** The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).